# What is the name of the following kinds of patterns?

Tags: technique-identification

I have found the following patterns online and am wondering what exactly they are called?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mathematical term for this kind of pattern would be *[pmm wallpaper](http://www2.clarku.edu/~djoyce/wallpaper/wall6.html)* pattern.  There are seventeen types of repeating planar patterns, and this is one of the simplest ones.

The characteristics of the pattern are based on it having perpendicular symmetry axes through the centers of each of the tessellation units.  There are also 180 degree rotation symmetries about these centers, with no additional glide reflection symmetries.

Comment: I removed the 0 as I did not understand why it was there. If that is required feel free to roll back the edit.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it would be called a tessellated pattern where a single shape is repeated without overlap.